# Вычисление координат вершины кривой Безье;

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

имеется кривая безье построенная по 3 точкам. как определить реальные координаты высоты отрисованной кривой?! Использую CreateJS (EaselJS) функция `Graphics.BezierCurveTo ( cp1x  cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, x, y )`
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1):

Метод дорогой, находим все точки, лежащие на кривой. Затем сортируем по Х.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let w = canvas.width = 500;
let h = canvas.height = 180;

let curve = new Path2D('M 10 10 Q 500 20 10 170');

ctx.stroke(curve);

let points = [];

for(let x = 0; x < w; x++){
    for(let y = 0; y < h; y++){
        if(ctx.isPointInStroke(curve, x, y)){
                points.push([x,y]);
        }
    }
}

let extremum = points.sort((a,b) => b[0] - a[0])[0];

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(extremum[0], extremum[1], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Можно немного короче: перебирать точки с конечной X (`x = w`) и вернуть первую же точку, лежащую на кривой.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let w = canvas.width = 500;
let h = canvas.height = 180;

let curve = new Path2D('M 10 10 Q 500 20 10 170');

ctx.stroke(curve);

let extremum = (() => {
    for(let x = w; x >= 0; x--){
        for(let y = 0; y < h; y++){
            if(ctx.isPointInStroke(curve, x, y)){
                    return [x,y];
            }
        }
    }
})();

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(extremum[0], extremum[1], 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: `isPointInStroke` в easeljs нет такой функции и до сих пор решения получить так и не удалось(

Comment: Вообще нужно узнать не выходит ли линия кривая за пределы размеров 800x600

Comment: Значит надо копаться в библиотеке и находить path, чтобы подставить в isPointInStroke. Это метод контекста холста, ему не нужна поддержка библиотеки.